# Live validation in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, livevalidation

In my HTML page I use the [Live Validation library](http://livevalidation.com/)

My problem however is when I input a correct value, the library shows 'Does not match!' and when I clear all input, it validates correctly. This is my code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery/livevalidation.js"></script>

<p>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <form:password id="password" path="password" tabindex="4" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
        <form:password id="conformPassword" path="conformPassword" tabindex="5" />
    </p>
-----
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         ValidCaptcha();
     });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidCaptcha() {
        var password1 = new LiveValidation('conformPassword');
        password1.add( Validate.Confirmation, { match: 'password' } );
    }
</script>
```

What goes wrong here?

Comment: Hear live validation give error when we give correct input..

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this code, but the resulting html code might be different from what this code snippet suggests (modified by other parts of the application). Check the rendered HTML code if all is as expected there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this example based on your code....it's working btw:

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://livevalidation.com/javascripts/src/1.3/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidCaptcha() {
            var password1 = new LiveValidation('conformPassword');
            password1.add( Validate.Confirmation, { match: 'password' } );
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
          ValidCaptcha();

        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password"  tabindex="4" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="conformPassword" tabindex="5" />

        </p>
    -----


    </body>

    </html>
```

Tested on my localhost; i switch the order of the javascript.

Saludos ;)